# MySQL DELETE query issue with Select

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

The following query:

```
DELETE FROM CO05IN.ININVPRC WHERE IPPART IN (SELECT IPPART FROM CO05IN.ININVPRC left join CO05IN.ININVMST on IPPART = IMPART where IMPART is null);
```

Creates this on the log: You can't specify target table 'ININVPRC' for update in FROM clause.

What is causing this?

Note using MySQL version 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way.

```
DELETE FROM CO05IN.ININVPRC WHERE IPPART IN (select * from (SELECT IPPART FROM CO05IN.ININVPRC left join CO05IN.ININVMST on IPPART = IMPART where IMPART is null) as t);
```

Comment: It might have been that I was using MySQL workbench and I needed to disable "Forbid UPDATE and DELETE statements without a WHERE clause (safe updates). Requires a reconnection." ... But I didn't see that message until I tried the above query.